# Intuition behind output neuron error signal in backpropagation

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I have a potentially obvious question about neural network error backpropagation.

In Andrej Karpathy's [blog post](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/) on neural networks, he goes through an example of backpropagation.

When calculating the error gradient at the output of the network (which is then backpropagated to get the derivative of the output error with respect to each weight), he does:

```
dscores = probs
dscores[range(num_examples),y] -= 1
dscores /= num_examples,
```

where `probs` is an array where each row represents an output class probability distribution for a given training observation, `num_examples` is the number of training observations, and `y` is the output class (which corresponds to an index of the `dscores` array.

Can anyone briefly explain why he divides each observation by the number of training examples? I'm struggling to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone briefly explain why he divides each observation by the number of training examples?

`dscores` is the gradient computed based on all samples of the mini-batch (or in the tutorial you pointed to, the entire training set): it is divided by `num_examples` in order not to depend on size of the mini-batch (i.e., the number of samples in the mini-batch). It is commonplace to do so, e.g. this way, you don't have to change `step_size` if `num_examples` changes.